# TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%d %d')` when saving pandas file to text

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

I am trying to save a line of panda values into a textfile, but I get the `Error: TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%d %d')`
Can anyone explain me what that means and how to fix it? 
What I specifically want to do is that each time this function is called a new line  with the 3 panda values is written to that textfile and if the file does not exist it should be created

```
lambda_pathlet=0.001
pathlets_learned=30
trajectory_amount=65

def saveLambdaAndFrequency(lambdaPathlet, pathlets_learned,trajectory_amount):
    columns = ["lambda", "pathlets_learned", "trajectory_amount"]
    df_lambda_pathlets=pd.DataFrame(columns)
    df_lambda_pathlets = df_lambda_pathlets.set_value(lambdaPathlet, pathlets_learned,trajectory_amount)
    res= "\"lambda\" \"pathlets_learned\" \"trajectory_amount\""
    lambda_auswertung = 'Lambda_Pathlet_Auswertung.txt'
    f = open(lambda_auswertung, 'w+')
    with open(lambda_auswertung, 'w+') as f:
        np.savetxt(f,df_lambda_pathlets.values,comments='',fmt='%d',header=res)
    f.close()
```

Comment: What if you simply do not pass the `fmt` argument at all?  Does it work?

Comment: Same but says `TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e')`

Comment: How about `fmt='%s'`?

Comment: That works, thanks a lot @JohnZwinck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data is of `object` type, you should print it using `fmt='%s'` to get the `str()` conversion of each value, rather than `fmt='%d'` which converts to integers.